# Return Value from coroutine to composable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines

I am making a music player app with **Jetpack Compose**.and running into problems with returning *Bitmap* track thumbnails from **viewmodel** to the LazyColumn displaying
the *TrackCard* composables for each track.

LazyColumn Displaying the TrackCards

```
      @Composable
      fun MainScreen(musiclist: List<Track>, viewmodel: TrackListViewModel,
           context: Context,
           requestBitmap: (Int)-> Unit){
            LazyColumn{
            item {
                musiclist.forEach {
                track ->
                    TrackCard(
                    title = track.track_title,
                    Artist = track.track_artist,
                    album = track.track_album,
                    length = track.track_length,
                    isSelected = false,
                    albumArt = {/**What to do here */}
                ) }}}}
```

ViewModel Functions returning thumbnails: **I have used suspendCoroutine to return Bitmap value,,if you suggest that their is a better way please tell me about it**

```
     suspend fun getThumbnail(context: Context,index : Int) : Bitmap {
        return suspendCoroutine {
         loadBitmapOnRequest(context, musicList[index].track_uri)

       }
       }
       private fun loadBitmapOnRequest(context : Context, uri:Uri) : Bitmap{
       val mediaMetadataRetriever = MediaMetadataRetriever()
       mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(context,uri)
       val byte1: ByteArray? = mediaMetadataRetriever.embeddedPicture
       mediaMetadataRetriever.release()
       return if(byte1 != null){
        BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byte1, 0, byte1.size)
       }
       else{
        albumArt!!
       }}
```

Composable Card

```
          @Composable
          fun TrackCard(title: String?,
          Artist: String?,
          album : String?,
          length : Float,
          isSelected: Boolean,
          albumArt : Bitmap){

    Card(backgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
        border = BorderStroke(2.dp,Color.Transparent),
        modifier = Modifier
            .wrapContentHeight()
            .fillMaxWidth(),

    ) {
        //Album Art Row
        Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.20f).fillMaxHeight(0.20f)) {
            AsyncImage(albumArt, contentDescription =null,
            )
        }
        Row() {
            Column(modifier =Modifier.padding(start = 3.dp,
                top = 2.dp, bottom = 2.dp)){
                Row(horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Start) {
                    title?.let {
                        Text(
                            text = it, fontSize = 19.sp,
                            maxLines = 1, overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                            fontFamily = rubik, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
                        )
                    }
                }
                Row(horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Start) {
                    Artist?.let {
                        Text(
                            text = it, fontSize = 9.sp, fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold,
                            fontFamily = rubik, maxLines = 1, overflow =   TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.25f)
                        )
                        }}}}}}
```

so I am trying to call the ***getThumbnail()*** from the ***LazyColumn()*** to provide the ***TrackCard()*** with the bitmap...please help me know how to call it from the coroutine and what is the best way...and if there are any way i can enhance this code...I would really appreciate any help, thanks